# How to update android app data dynamically from the internet through web services and APis

Tags: java, android, api, rest, parsing

I want to make an app whose data could be changed dynamically from the internet on the daily basis.I know about web APIs , REST ,SOAP but I am not clear about them .Could someone please explain me thoroughly or could post some links from where I can learn.i have also heard about parse.com , does that help to use it as a database service ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).  Parse.com is discontinuing service January 2017.  They have [open-sourced the parse platform](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) so you can run it on your own.

Comment: It is about how to get the data from the server ,but can you tell me how to post data on to the server initially so my app can fetch that.